# PhpSpreadsheet save and keep style

Tags: php, excel, phpspreadsheet

I use PhpSpreadsheet to read and write an Excel files, I would like to save the file with the style (picture, font style, color, etc).

I don't find the way in the doc of PhpSpreadsheet

I can save the file with just the data and not all the style :

```
$reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xls();
$reader->setReadDataOnly(true);
$spreadsheet = $reader->load("myFile.xls");

// Code ...

$writer = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xls');
$writer->save('mySavedFile.xls');
```

How can i save the file with the style ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, it's easy ! I just remove this : `$reader->setReadDataOnly(true);`

Code :

```
$reader = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Reader\Xls();
// $reader->setReadDataOnly(true);
$spreadsheet = $reader->load("myFile.xls");

// Code ...

$writer = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xls');
$writer->save('mySavedFile.xls');
```